# Problems with GFCI outlets recently installed

Tags: lighting, gfci

I had 3 GFCI outlets installed recently in my home in by a contractor and now have some  lights that do not work at all.  The contractor put one in my kitchen, one in my 2nd floor bathroom and one in my basement.

The light above my kitchen sink would not work, so a relative who has done electrical work over many years spent nearly 3 hours correcting the outlet in the kitchen.  The light above the sink now works, but there is a light switch in the kitchen that turns on a floodlight in the back yard, and it will not work at all.  There are two ceiling lights on my third floor that always worked, but now one will not work at all.  I have never had any problems before with any lights not working, and believe the problem has to do with the outlets not being connected properly, especially since the one my relative spent 3 hours working on was not installed properly.

I called the contractor & explained the situation, but he states that the fact that the lights now don't work at all has nothing to do with what they did.  I would appreciate some insight or advice as to what the cause of the problem may be.

Comment: Can you get photos of the inside of the GFCI boxes in the basement and 2nd floor bathroom?  Turn the circuit breakers for those circuits off, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Some insight and advice: hire an electrician for this.  If you'd done that in the beginning you wouldn't be here asking for insight and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some of the outlets were on 1/2  Switched outlet Circuit? It is also possible that the power feeling the outlet is also feeding the switch for the lights and he didn't correctly tap the incoming power for the LINE side of the GFCI.  Adding a GFCI Breaks the continuity of the incoming power so it must travel through the receptacle vs the receptacle being a TAP form the power. See how many wires are in the GFCI outlet and check the sides they are connected to, line vs. load. Lights should be on Line. tripping the GFCI should not make lights not work just other outlets.

Comment: If there is moisture in the outdoor light fixture it might be tripping the GFCI even if everything is wired correctly.